# How to split strings using space before posting into mysql

Tags: php, mysql

```
if (mysqli_connect_errno()==0)
{ // if successfully connected

  $sent_dt=$_POST['scts'];
  // important: escape string values 
  $txt=mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['text']);
  $snd=mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['sender']);

  // creating an sql statement to insert the message into the SMS_IN table
  $sql="INSERT INTO SMS_IN(studentID,lastname,firstname,class) VALUES ('34','Lekan','Balogun','Grade8')";
  // executing the sql statement
  $insert_sms_success = mysqli_query($con,$sql);

  // closing the connection
  mysqli_close($con);
}
```

Please, I'm new to php and I got this code from a friend for my project. I want to split the text message using spaces (e.g 34 Lekan Balogun Grade8) before its inserted into my database. My table fields are: StudentID, LastName, FirstName, Class and so I will want it posted as 34 for ID, Lekan for Lastname, Balogun for Firstname and Grade8 entered into class. Thanks in anticipation.

Comment: explode() on " " character

Comment: You can explode on a space, but if there are any spaces that shouldn't be in the string then it won't work.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [explode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) funnction in php for this

```
$str = '34 Lekan Balogun Grade8';
$arr = explode(' ',$str);
echo '<pre>';
print_r($arr);
```

Comment: Any reason for the downvote Mr.Downvotter

Comment: I think that downvoter has written why he did that in comment in question.

Comment: Ahh again without a reason one more down vote.Why arent you saying the reason and downvotting it.?

Comment: can i automatically post what is exploded? Thanx a great deal

Answer (score 2):

You can split the string values using "explode" function,

```
 $textArray = @explode(" ",$txt);

  echo "<pre>";
  print_r($textArray);
  echo "</pre>";
```

Answer (score 1):

This is you complete code
     if (mysqli_connect_errno()==0)
                { // if successfully connected

```
              $sent_dt=$_POST['scts'];
              // important: escape string values 
              $txt=mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['text']);
              $snd=mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['sender']);
                $arr = explode(' ',$txt);
                echo '<pre>';
                print_r($arr);
                $StudentID = $arr['0'];
                $LastName  = $arr['1'];
                $FirstName = $arr['2'];
                $Class     = $arr['3']

              // creating an sql statement to insert the message into the SMS_IN table
              $sql="INSERT INTO SMS_IN(sms_text,sender_number,sent_dt) VALUES ('$txt','$snd','$sent_dt')";
              // executing the sql statement
              $insert_sms_success = mysqli_query($con,$sql);

              // closing the connection
              mysqli_close($con);
  }
?>
```

Comment: I was told to avoid using 'print' but instead use 'echo' to boost speed. Can i avoid using print and can the exploded data be posted automatically? Thanx

Comment: You can use var_dump instead of print_r to see data